# I disable IE enhanced security but IE not working

Tags: internet-explorer, amazon-ec2, windows-server

I have connect windows EC2 instance via RDP,In windows Internet explorer not working,I already disable enhanced security but it's not working. I attached the screenshot please find.

[image: Error]

Comment: "I already disable enhanced security". Nope. The screenshot indicates that you didn't disable it.

Comment: I disable enhanced security but if I open IE then this error shows it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is second error after disable IE Enhanced Security
> [View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMYtg.png)

This issue is related to the IE Browser Home page setting, if you click the IE tools and open the Internet Options, on the General tab, you can see the home page like this:

[image]

Try to change the Home page setting and replace the home page, after that, click the Apply button to save the change, like below:

[image]

Then, re-open the IE browser, it will show the default home page.

Comment: After setting the default home page, is there any error message?

Comment: IE loading,does not happen next

Comment: Please check the http inbound and outbound rules, and make sure you have set it. Also, you could check the firewall whether the port is enabled. If still not working, try to use  F12 developer tools to check whether there is some error?

Answer (score 5):

There is a bug in Server Manager for disabling Internet Explorer Enhanced Security that goes back 7+ years and is still present in Windows Server 2019. If Enhanced Security is not disabled as your first step on connecting to the server, when you later add new users, they are stuck on Enhanced Security. Several infuriating websites suggest all you need to do is go to Server Manager, click Local Server, then IE Enhanced Security Configuration and turn it off. The problem is that in many cases, it already is off. An additional frustration is that if you come in via remote desktop and connect to a domain, unless you have administrative rights over the local computer, you won't be able to turn it off, or if it is off in Server Manger, IE will still show it is in enhanced security mode.

Some users suggest hacking into the registry, but I found this solution:

1) If you don't have administrative rights over the local machine for the user who is stuck in IE Enhanced Security, add those in. This might require a log in to the local machine with administrative rights, then START...Edit Local Users and Groups..Click on Groups, Click on Administrators, right click Add to Group... and add in the domain\user you want to fix as a member of Administrators. Now log out, log in as the user who is stuck in IE Enhanced Security. Remember that if you add a user to Administrators, you must log out and back in again for that change to take effect.

2) You should now be logged into Windows Server with administrative rights. You can click on IE and show that you are in Enhanced Security mode. You can do START...Server Manager..Local Server, and see the Microsoft bug where IE Enhanced Security is turned off, even though it obviously is on.

3) Don't despair. Instead, turn ON Enhanced Security by clicking on the link. Yes, do the opposite of what you want to accomplish.

4) Close and open IE. Show you are still stuck in Enhanced Security. Close IE again.

5) Now, in Server Manager, click on the IE Enhanced Security and turn it OFF.

6) Re-open IE and show that now, finally, Enhanced Security has been turned off.

Some users suggest just using Chrome or Firefox, but the problem for developers is that the WebBrowser object runs off Internet Explorer with IE's security features. Enhanced Mode must be disabled for that software to work.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, this helped me. Could you please point us to the link of this bug.

Comment: I had the same issue and this worked perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following steps to turn off Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration on windows server:

1. Close any Internet Explorer browser windows that you might have open.
2. Open Server Manager
3. If your server is running Windows Server® 2008 R2, in the Security Information section of Server Summary, click Configure IE ESC to open the Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration dialog.

   If your server is running Windows Server® 2012, click Configure this local server to open the Local Server configuration page. Then, in the Properties area, next to IE Enhanced Security Configuration, click On to open the Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration dialog.
4. To allow members of the local Administrators group to use Internet Explorer in its default client configuration, under Administrators click Off.

   To allow members of all other groups to use Internet Explorer in its default client configuration, under Users click Off.

   Note
   Once the Internet Explorer Enhanced Configuration is turned off for one set of users, Server Manager will display Off next to Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration.
5. Click OK to apply your changes.

Comment: Thanks,but i already perform this step but IE can't work, display  this error

Comment: Caution: Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration is not enabled
Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration configures your server and Internet Explorer in a way that decreases the exposure of your server to potential attacks through Web content and application scripts. This is done by raising the default security levels on Internet Explorer security zones and changing the default settings.

Comment: @promis can you make a screenshot of the place where you disabled it? In a Windows server, there are multiple places where you can disable it, but only 1 of those places works for Windows servers

Answer (score 0):

This is second error after disable IE Enhanced Security
[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMYtg.png)